# Xcode Accessing iFile Directories

Tags: xcode, directory

I have searched for a week and I checkkd all forums I know for an answer to the following Question. Then I thought the creator of Crackulous HAS to know how it works. So it would be great if he answers me here or through PM.

First of all Crackulous:

If I am right, Crackulous first find all Apps installed on the Device (in iFile var/mobile/Applications). Then it checks whether it is encrypted or decrypted.
If it's encrypted, it shows as if it is already decrypted and not visible.
So if I am right Docmorelli has to access or display the Directory var/mobile/Applications. Or has to access it to check if its decrypted or encrypted.

So I have a Project in Xcode where I need this information: I have to access var/mobile/Applications

e.g I am a Cheater so I cheat lots of Games.

I want to make a Button that when people click on it, it places a file in var/mobile/Applications....

So Docmorelli or any other Developer: Please tell me how can I access var/mobile/Applications with xcode!

I really need it!

e.g code: (not really objective c)

```
if buttonName clicked write File in var/mobile/Applications/Game.app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your application in `/Applications`. If you do that your program will launch with the permissions to write to the folder you specified.

Xcode can't do it, so place it there manually with SSH or something similar.